# error when adding computed property names webpack babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I tried to replace numbers i am using for to map data with variables so then i can easy update values in one place only.

```
const allowedViews = {
    32: { /* something */ },
    56: { /* something */ },
    ...
}
module.exports = { allowedViews, ... };
```

i replaced above with:

```
const someView = 32;
const someOtherView = 56;
const allowedViews = {
    [someView]: { /* something */ },
    [someOtherView]: { /* something */ },
    ...
}

module.exports = { allowedViews, ... };
```

After this change i am getting following error:

`Uncaught Error: ES Modules may not assign module.exports or exports.*, Use ESM export syntax, instead: 83305`

babel config:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-computed-properties",
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions"
    ]
}
```

webpack config

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
        filename: "js/main.[fullhash:8].js",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                type: "asset",
                generator: {
                    filename: "assets/[name].[hash][ext]",
                },
                parser: {
                    dataUrlCondition: {
                        maxSize: 20 * 1024, // 20kb
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|sass|css)$/i,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "postcss-loader",
                    "sass-loader",
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json"],
    },
    plugins: [htmlPlugin, miniCssExtractPlugin],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: {
            rewrites: [{ from: /^\/$/, to: "/index.html" }],
        },
    },
};
```

Does someone have clue why after replacing hardcoded numbers with computed property names this problems happens? I know its the reason because if i revert this change and go back to hardcoded numbers application is working properly.

Comment: I doubt how it is working initially. This error which you're getting is related to using ES Modules (ESM) syntax in a CommonJS module. In other words, you are trying to use module.exports in a file where you are also using ES6 import/export syntax. Will you mind sharing your full code and where you're using it? One brute force idea I can suggest in you Babel file try adding:
`"presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env", { "modules": "commonjs" }],
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
`